# Wordpress user_register hook not executing?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm creating a Worldpress Plugin for my own purpose.
I'd like to add some additional fields to the registration form (First Name, Last Name and Phone Number)

```
<?php 
function __construct() {
    ....
    add_action( 'register_form', array($this, 'eddpremium_register_additonalfields' ));
    add_filter( 'registration_errors', array($this, 'eddpremium_register_errors'), 10, 3 );
    add_action( 'user_register', array($this, 'eddpremium_register_fields_save'), 10, 1 );
    ....

    add_action( 'user_contactmethods', array($this, 'eddpremium_mobilenumber_setting' ));
}
```

The `register_form` hook as well the `registration_errors` filter are working fine, but `user_register` doesn't. It seems, that the function, which should save the additonal fields, doesn't get fired...

```
function eddpremium_register_fields_save($user_id) {

    $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
    $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
    $mobile_phone = $_POST["mobile_phone"];

    // No need to check, variables get checked in registration_errors


    update_user_meta($user_id, "first_name", $first_name);
    update_user_meta($user_id, "last_name", $last_name);
    update_user_meta($user_id, "mobile_phone", $mobile_phone);

    //$username = get_userdata($user_id)->user_login;

}
```

Strangley, after the successful registration `user_contactmethods` gets fired.
How can I get the `user_register` hook to work properly?

#### Picture of the problem causing:

(This function shouldn't be fired after registration, however it get's fired)

[image: Problem]

Code of the function which shouldn't get executed at that point:

```
function eddpremium_mobilenumber_setting() {

    $userid = $_GET["user_id"]; // Zu bearbeitende Nutzerid
    if(empty($userid))  // wenn aktueller Nutzer eigenes Profil bearbeitet
        $userid = get_current_user_id();

        $mobile_phone_verified = get_the_author_meta('mobile_phone_verified', $userid);

    ?>

        <tr>
            <th><label for="mobile_phone">Handynummer:</label></th>
            <td>
                <input id="mobile_phone" name="mobile_phone" autocomplete="off" <?php if(empty($mobile_phone_verified) AND !current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?> placeholder="0791112233" type="tel" value="<?php $mobile_phone = get_the_author_meta( 'mobile_phone', $userid ); 
                        echo $mobile_phone ? $mobile_phone : '';?>" />
                 <?php if(empty($mobile_phone_verified)) {?>    <a style='color:red;'>Verifikation erforderlich</a>   <?php } else {?>
                    <a style='color:green;'>Nummer verifiziert</a>
                    <?php }   ?>
            
            </td>


        </tr>

    <?php

}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: @milankyada The `user_register` hook doesn't get fired...

Comment: I've tried https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form and it's working good. You should try this. I think no need to pass priority and parameter in `add_action`. :)

Comment: @milankyada I used this too.. Unfortunately, it's still not working without priority and parameter... another function gets executed and causes modify header information error.... i will post picture in the question body

Comment: can you please write wp_die() function for testing purpose, so you can get idea about you hook is actually calling or not.
write `wp_die();` before this line `$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];`
You can write `print_r($_POST)` to check passing values before `wp_die();`

Comment: Doesn't work. Either the `user_contactmethods` hooks before (and dies cause the error above [but why should that hook here???]) or the hook doesn't fire. Registration Mail arrives. @milankyada

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120837/discussion-between-dario-ackermann-and-milan-kyada).

Comment: I am not sure extract problem without live check. But you can try for testing purpose disable wp debug in wp-config.php file define('WP_DEBUG', false). If the problem is present you can try this hook to save extra user meta for testing purpose like add_action( 'register_new_user', 'eddpremium_register_fields_save');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`user_register` doesn't fire every time, on updating existing profile, `profile_update` is fired...

Just add your callback to both actions, so that it fires on updating too ;)

```
add_action( 'user_register', array($this, 'eddpremium_register_fields_save'), 10, 1 );
add_action( 'profile_update', array($this, 'eddpremium_register_fields_save'), 10, 1 );
```

---

### UPDATE

WP checks if `ID` (user ID) is passed with form data, if it is, `profile_update` hook is fired. Otherwise `user_register` is.

Comment: WTF. Works like a charm. Why is `profile_update` fireing and `user_register` not? Will give you bounty soon. Thanks!

Comment: Btw. now it works but when I try my methods it throws an memory exhaust message. Recently updated to wordpress 5.6.. rollback? get ini_get_all error too...

Comment: Memory exhausted errors are very difficult to address, you can try rolling back, but most of the times you simply need more resources to do the stuff and you have to increase the memory limit.

Comment: It was a problem caused by Wordpress 4.6. After rollback to 4.5.3 everything works now. Thank you very much for the explanation, the `user_register`didn't fire cause there was an interference by another plugin. Changed wp_update_user to wp_update_user_meta (or similar) and no more memory limit error. 

Again, thank you!!!!

Answer (score -1):

I am new to wordpress plugin development too. But since the 'eddpremium_register_fields_save' doesn't work correctly when called in an add_action method why not define an anonymous function inside the add_action methode? I think that the argument that 'eddpremium_register_fields_save' must have is what is causing problem in your call.