# user_register hook doesn't fire

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I have designed a plugin and in a part of its functionalities I'm trying to save some data to a custom table in MySQL based on the ID of new registered user in **Wordpress** registration form. I used **user_register** hook as follow:

```
function my_func($user_id){

    // some DB Query code based on $user_id
}

add_action('user_register', 'my_func', 10, 1);
```

I already tried solution in [Wordpress user_register hook not executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923627/wordpress-user-register-hook-not-executing)
and used **profile_update** hook as described there
but it couldn't help. I also tried changing priority value and removed it but the problem still exists.

The only thing I want is to have access to ID of the new registered user in registration form.
I appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

I finally could find the solution. Actually in the body of *myfunc* function in the question I was trying to output the **$user_id** using javascript alert and for some reason that script doesn't run at that point but my query runs successfully and the way that I used the **user_register** hook is correct.

I just want to share it in case anybody encountered such a problem.

Thanks.